# How to do addition ("+") between fields with CriteriaBuilder with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, criteriabuilder

I'm trying to use criteria builder to add several field together and then apply a sql function.
I try to sum it and with only two field, it is possible but when i have a third one, i cannot apply the "+" easily.

```
 select.add(cb.min(cb.sum(functionListToAdd.get(0), functionListToAdd.get(1))));
 cq.multiselect(select);
 em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

This case works but i need more parameter and the sum function doesn't allowed more than 2 Expression (parameter).

Do you know how to sum field like the example below with CriteriaBuilder API ?

To illustrate what i want i did a request sql which work (i remove some code to be more readable)

SQL Example of what i want :

```
select
    min(**b1_0.ecpi + s1_0.ecpi + l1_0.ecpi**),
    max(b1_0.ecpi + s1_0.ecpi + l1_0.ecpi),
    cast('units' as text) 
from
    facility.facility b1_0,
    facility.cost s1_0 ,
    facility.shipping l1_0
```

Thanks a lot to help me because i'm locked because of a simple "+".

Comment: I think you got that right - no easy way to add 3 columns unfortunately. If `A`, `B`, `C` are the columns/fields you want to add, it would be `cb.sum(A, cb.sum(B, C))`.

Comment: Really nothing else ? because i have 10-15 parameters to sum and it will be hard to understand and to implement a simple addition

Comment: You got yourself in trouble didn't you :D Well, in that case what I would do is write a function that takes an arbitrary number of `cb.sum`-compatible arguments and iteratively applies `cb.sum` on them. At least the code that builds the query will be cleaner!

Comment: yes, i'm in trouble alone ^^ and in fact, it's more complicate that explain, i have 10/15 param to sum, then divide this by another big sum, then multiply result by another field to find a percent and then use it for generate plot... i'm scared...

Comment: It might be helpful to build a library class to handle this complexity.  Provide the inputs as fields and return the expression for each type of function, sum(... fields), multiple(...), divide(...), etc.

Comment: It's not a solution, merely a pain killer... but you can assign the 2 big sums to properly named variables and, using the vararg summation function, still have a moderately sane expression for your full calculation. Like `var sum1 = cbsum(A, B, C); var sum2 = cbsum(D, E, F); cb.prod(cb.quot(sum1, sum2), G);` (I said *moderately* sane :D )

Answer (score 0):

You can always try compounding statements:

```
cb.sum(functionListToAdd.get(0), cb.sum(functionListToAdd.get(1), functionListToAdd.get(2)))
```

Comment: i try it with your chaining sum and it works correctly so thank you Nikos and gagarwa

Answer (score 0):

in order to do your advice i share a function which work for me.

You just have to put a real Expression in sumExpression as third parameter.

```
  Expression initExpression = functionListToAdd.remove(functionListToAdd.size()-1);
  select.add(cb.min(sumExpression(cb, functionListToAdd, initExpression)));

private Expression sumExpression(CriteriaBuilder cb, List<Expression> functionListToAdd, Expression expression) {
    if (functionListToAdd.size() <= 1) {
        return cb.sum(functionListToAdd.get(0), expression);
    } else {
        Expression expressionTemp = functionListToAdd.remove(functionListToAdd.size()-1);
        return cb.sum(expressionTemp, sumExpression(cb, functionListToAdd, expression));
    }
}
```